# Changed to div not getting reflected on browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to update the div dynamically, I can see the content being added to the div when I see the inspect element but I cannot see it on browser .

```
<script ="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var baseURL = 'aaa.html';
            //load content for first tab and initialize
     $.get('aaa.html', function (data) {
       var parser = new DOMParser()
       var el = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
       var text = el.getElementById("container");
       var home_object = document.getElementById("home");
       var content = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(text);
       home_object.appendChild(text) ;
       console.log(home_object);
       });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I see that you are using jQuery but at the same time you are using JavaScript to select the id of the element... Any reason for this? Because you could just so easily do `$('#home').append(text)` and that should accomplish the same thing.

Comment: yeah why would you not jsut do `$.get('aaa.html', function (data) {  $(data).find('#container').appendTo('#home')});`

Comment: No, I am actually new to UI, so just trying out different things.

Comment: I want to replace the content inside the div with id home with the content that I extract from aaa.html

Comment: @prodigitalson, I tried the command you gave me but it dosen't work

Comment: I also tried  home_object.innerHTML = content. But could not get the page to reflect the updated div

Answer (score 2):

Only jQuery:

```
$.get('aaa.html', function (data) {
   var $content = $(data).find('#container');
   // this would replace 
   $('#home').html($content);

   // the following would append
   // $('#home').append($content);      
});
```

Comment: I tried the same thing, the content is not getting added to the div with id home. The issue with my code is that I can see the content being added but it is not reflected in the browser

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you see any errors on your console?

Comment: I used google chrome and firefox. I did not see any errors on console.

Comment: I have this code working here: http://jsfiddle.net/bd2g3q6e/2/ So im not sure whats going on... Is `#container` the first element in your response HTML? That could be part of it because then `find` wouldnt work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not necessarily appending the new content to existing content, you can use jQuery's ajax `.load()` method to reduce your code to:

```
$('#home').load( 'aaa.html #container' );
```

As for you not seeing the content in the browser, you probably have a class with `display:none` applied to either `#home` or some or all of the content you're loading. You may want to try something like:

```
   $('#home').load( 'aaa.html #container', function() {
       $(this).show();
   });
```

Or:

```
   $('#home').load( 'aaa.html #container', function() {
       $(this).find('*').show();
   });
```

Of course, if any of these shows the content, then you know that you should fix your css.

Comment: I tried this but it is still not working. My dashboard is using the sprockets framework. Does that make the difference. I am initializing my script inside my erb file